# Select child elements from child X to child X

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I need to add a class to child x to child x inside a div.

So in this example I want to add the class to child 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Now it's just adding the class to every third element.

Any good suggestions how this could be accomplished?

I have this HTML:

```
  <div id="days">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
  </div>
```

Jquery:

```
 day = 3;
 child_count = 10;
 $('#days > div:nth-child(' + day + 'n+' + child_count + ')').addClass('done');
```

Comment: Sorry a bit confused with the question.. Where exactly you want them to be added?

Comment: can you writte an example of the result you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Okey, understand :) I want to add the class to child 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is actually very simple:

```
$('#days > div').slice(start, end).addClass('done');
```

(`start` and `end` are zero based indexes)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpZhk/1/)
[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/slice/#slice-start-end)

Comment: Holly smokes +++ 1 loooong time! `:)`

Comment: Really nice, exactly what I needed! :) But it didn't add a class to the "start" child, so I just added a -1 to the start value. But it works as a charm! Thanks alot!!

Comment: @Kim, _"start and end **are zero based indexes**"_!

Answer (score 1):

**OR** could do this : http://jsfiddle.net/ZpZhk/ OR this http://jsfiddle.net/NzGVW/

Please note this is not dynamic and only cater ur specific case.

API `.netUntil` http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

API: `.nextAll` http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Hope it fits your specific needs else above is good `:)`

**code**

```
 $('#days > div:nth-child(3)').nextAll().addClass('done');

 alert($('#days').html());
```

**Update**

```
 $('#days > div:nth-child(3)').nextUntil($('#days > div:nth-child(10)') , "div" ).addClass('done');
```

Comment: You select even 11,12,13. and nice seeing you again!

Comment: @gdoron Bruvo, I feel O for Owesome to see you `:)`. saweet,thanks used `nextUntil` now `:)` check this out http://jsfiddle.net/NzGVW/

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using [:gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and [:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/):

```
$("#days > div:gt(" + (day-2) + ")").filter(':lt(' + (child_count) + ')').addClass('done');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLxzc/)**

All indexes for lt and gt are 0 based. gt will select the items greater than your start count, so gt will be `day-2` i.e select all greater than index 1, (i.e 2nd which is 3rd item), and filter it to get the items less than your count.

Comment: Why not ++1 to you as well yo!

Comment: @Tats_innit Thanks. Happily received... :)